# Function selection for copying string in C++, with focus on performance

Tags: c, string, performance, copy

I am writing a piece of code that needs to copy values from one char pointer to another. The primary requirements are that the code should work as fast as possible and across as many platforms as possible.

I see that I can do this string copy using either of these two functions:

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

and

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

How can I determine what will be best for my requirements?

In general, how can I find out relative speeds of two different functions (across platforms)?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use neither and go with `std::copy_n` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From performance POV, `memcpy` is faster, as it doesn't check the content itself, just copying it.

And regarding compatibility - memcpy is part of the C standard.

Comment: _If_ you end up copying the same amount of data then `memcpy` is probably faster.  However `strncpy` may be faster if the typical string length is less than the maximum buffer size.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y only if the typical string is a **little bit** shorter than the buffer size AND if the length itself is not too big (because of the test overhead for each byte): a copy operation can be much more faster than a set operation.

Answer (score 6):

They don't do the same thing. If you're certain the source and destination buffers are the same size, go with `memcpy`. If not, `strncpy` does bound checking and it's the way to go.

But unless you do millions of operations, this shouldn't be a factor in your decision. Do some profiling first, see how much time (if any) you save by using `memcpy`.

Comment: `strncpy` does not do bound checking! If `num` is greater than the length of `dest`, `strncpy` wouldn't know it. But `strncpy` affords some safety in the sense that `strncpy` nulls remaining bytes if `s2` is shorter than `num` bytes.

Comment: @PavanManjunath I meant that it checks the bound of source and fills destination according to that (if it's bigger).

Comment: @Luchian: The documentation for memcpy makes no mention that the source and destination should be of the same size (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy), am I missing something? Or are you saying that the data type pointed to by source and destination should be the same?
And I am doing 100s of millions of operations.

Comment: @ShaileshTainwala I didn't say that. What I mean is that if source is lower than the number of bytes you want to copy, the rest of dest is filled with 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to copy strings (unless you know their size in advance) you should always use `strncpy`.

Even if underlying implementation is not so different `memcpy` is much faster because it does not have to check what it's copying, `strncpy` will stop when it'll copy the *end of string* character (`NULL`).

**EDIT**
Some considerations about performance of `strncpy` compared to `memcpy`.
We can suppose to have two - for example - 512 bytes buffers and we want to copy the content (a `NULL` terminatd string of - say - 32 characters) from the first buffer to the second one.

**What `strncpy` will do**: will copy, byte per byte, from the source to the target. It'll stop when it'll copy the `NULL` character and then it'll set everything else to 0. This is a possible implementation of this function:

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    char *ret = dest;
    do {
        if (!n--)
            return ret;
    } while (*dest++ = *src++);
    while (n--)
        *dest++ = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

**What `memcpy` will do**: will bulk copy everything from the source to the target. This is a possible implementation of this function:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    char *dp = dest;
    const char *sp = src;
    while (n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    return dest;
}
```

Even if both versions are **not** optimized you can see that it performs much less operations but it can be slower only when the string length is much shorter than the total buffer length (it'll save the `*sp++` in the second `while`). So even testing for performance isn't reliable because it depends on the *real* inputs (so you should have some sort of statistical data from **real world**).

**Considerations**
Moreover we should remember that true implementations are not so simple!!! Look this implementation of `strncpy`:
http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strncpy.c;h=f6ee27832da95d9da9aef8a6fcf73f53f997c796;hb=HEAD

Now look at `memcpy` implementation:
http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memcpy.c;h=3080fcb4de4cec83a57b65bf07995a1e41abb1f6;hb=HEAD

`memcpy` will always be faster than `strncpy` for any real world situation  even in the corner case I spoke before (look PAGE_COPY_FWD_MAYBE).

**Note**
It's not your case because you will use it massively but in general I think that *if you have to copy a string then use strncpy*. Always. Probably you do not need any performance boost there, it'll handle NULL terminator for you and it'll be always clear you're copying a string to whom will read your code.
Your case is different because you really do a lot of computation then if the buffer size is known you should use `memcpy` because it could be much much much more faster (specially if the buffer isn't tiny).

**References**
Demo implementations from: http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/
Performance test for memcpy: http://eetimes.com/design/embedded/4024961/Optimizing-Memcpy-improves-speed

Comment: strncpy stops as soon as it encounters NULL. So it gives us an impression that its faster than memcpy. But strncpy nulls all remaining bytes in the dest string if dest is greater than num bytes. This overhead might as well compensate for memcpys blind copy. SO, until we profile and check we cannot infer things concretely

Comment: @PavanManjunath not really, even if strncpy **may** copy less byte (and **may** perform a kind of memset) it'll always be slower, the bulk copy of memcpy isn't implemented with a loop to copy bytes but **at least** to copy blocks (and it'll check alignment).

Answer (score 1):

The functions you select here have different functionality. Chose the one that you need.

- memcpy will copy everything and both buffers need to be of the same size
- strncpy will copy from a smaller c-string and fill the rest of the target buffer with /0
- strcpy will copy only the string from target to destination (but you should use one of the safe variants).

Regarding performance: memcpy vs. strncpy - memcpy is faster but you need to know the size of the input string. strcpy may be the fastest if your string sizes vary much because it determines the required size while copying.